# Is it possible to add rate-limiting to Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: rest, powershell, powerbi

Every time I try to run this script, I encounter a 429 error (rate limiting) from the server. How can I slow it down, or reduce the rate so as to not encounter this error?

This is for data streaming to the PowerBI service through the PowerBI API. I've tried to see if I can find anything on how to implement rate limiting in combination with Invoke-RestMethod, but I'm unable to locate anything. I'm not sure if it's possible, or if another method ought to be used altogether. I can't find anything in the PowerBI documentation that would suggest that other alternative exist beside Invoke-RestMethod to send data to the API endpoint.

```
while($true) 
{
    Clear-Host;

    $SysDateTime = Get-Date -DisplayHint DateTime -Format F

    $SqlServer = 'nt-sql-db';
    $SqlDatabase = 'stream-db';

    $SqlConnectionString = 'Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=SSPI' -f $SqlServer, $SqlDatabase;
    $SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM dbo.streamTable;";

    $SqlCommand = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
    $SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlQuery;
    $SqlConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection -ArgumentList $SqlConnectionString;
    $SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection;

    $SqlConnection.Open();
    $SqlDataReader = $SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    ## identify the API endpoint
    $endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/beta/1234567890"

    ## structure the JSON payload
    while ($SqlDataReader.Read()) {
        $payload =  @{
            "name" =$SqlDataReader['name']                                         
            "queueTime" = $SqlDataReader['queueTime']                                    
            "promisedTime" =$SqlDataReader['promisedTime']                                   
            "sys_datetime" = $SysDateTime
            } 
        Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
    }

    $SqlConnection.Close();

    $SqlConnection.Dispose();

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30;
}
```

I have a loop here where the intention is to query a SQL server on the network and transmit data to the API endpoint over and over again so that the Power BI application shows data in quasi-real-time.

The script appears to run, but quickly encounters a 429 response from the server. For some reason, this didn't appear to start happening until the "historic data analysis" option was checking in Power BI, though I'm not sure I understand the impact and how that option would affect the functionality of this script.

Comment: `Invoke-WebRequest` cannot limit speed, use BITS.

Comment: @montonero It's not about limiting **speed**, it about how many calls per seconds are allowed (120 in this case).

Comment: @AndreyNikolov then I don't see what is the issue. Doing the requests less often should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are reading all rows from a table and pushing them one by one, and this in an endless loop. If there are more than 60 rows in your table, you will hit the [limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/api-rest-api-limitations) for POST rows requests per minute. The limits are as follows:

- 75 max columns
- 75 max tables
- 10,000 max rows per single POST rows request
- 1,000,000 rows added per hour per dataset
- 5 max pending POST rows requests per dataset
- **120 POST rows requests per minute per dataset**
- If table has 250,000 or more rows, 120 POST rows requests per hour per dataset
- 200,000 max rows stored per table in FIFO dataset
- 5,000,000 max rows stored per table in ‘none retention policy’ dataset
- 4,000 characters per value for string column in POST rows operation

This means that you are not allowed to make more than 120 port requests per minute, but you can add up to 10K rows with a single post, so simply change your code to read all the rows from your table (assuming they are less than 10K) and push them to the streaming dataset with a single post request. This way you will make only 2 requests per minute and you will not get 429 response.

Unless you enable historic data analysis, the dataset will keep the rows for the last hour only. If you enable it, the number of rows will keep growing and if they become more than 250K, the limit of 120 posts per minute will be lowered to 120 per **hour**, thus you will hit it even if there are 2 rows in your table. So this could explain the difference.

To push all rows from the dataset at once, you need to move the call to the API after the loop. Use the loop to initialize an array with all rows instead, and push this array to the service. Change the loop to looks like this:

```
## structure the JSON payload
$AllRows = @()
while ($SqlDataReader.Read()) {
    $CurrentRow =  @{
        "name" =$SqlDataReader['name']                                         
        "queueTime" = $SqlDataReader['queueTime']                                    
        "promisedTime" =$SqlDataReader['promisedTime']                                   
        "sys_datetime" = $SysDateTime
        } 
    $AllRows += $CurrentRow
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json $AllRows)
```

Comment: So would it be possible to adapt Invoke-RestMethod to post all the rows at once rather than going one-by-one? Thank you for your response, by the way.

Comment: Just move Invoke-RestMethod outside of the loop. Declare an array before the loop `$rows = @()`, inside the loop add the current row to it `$rows += $payload` and after the loop push all rows at once `-Body (ConvertTo-Json @($rows))`.

Comment: Declaring an array before the loop would mean placing `$rows = @()` just before the `while($true)`, right? It seems to be working if I place the `Invoke-RestMethod` outside of the `while($sqlDataReader.Read())` however? Would that be incorrect?

Comment: I modified my answer to show you how to change your loop so it will send all rows at once.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Andrey - this is exactly what I needed!